# Decompile a C file to Pro*C

Tags: c, decompiling

I'm currently working in Auditing a software we are supposed to start working on February. As part of the source code, we've recevied what seems to be a C file generated from a Pro*C file.

Pro*C files are compiled using the application "proc" into a C file, then you would use gcc to compile it into an actual executable file.

We are having some troubles with the previous owner of the application, and they refuse to provide us so far with the Pro*C file (pc extension).

I'm not sure if it's possible to revert it back from the C file to the Pro*C, using "proc" or any other tools.

Has anyone been able to do so, and if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `decompiler` for `C` to `*Proc`  file. A `C` file containing SQL statement in it is call an `embedded  *Proc`  file, an utility provided by Oracle. Once you translate this embedded file to  `C` by using a `proc` translator provided by Oracle it turn that `*Proc` file into a C file which modify these SQL statement with oracle provided library `APIs`.

Now my advice to you is, find out all the methods/functions in that `C` file (generated from a *Proc file) and check and understand what they are doing in Oracle database, especially all the database transactions. Once you understood that, just try to create your own `C` or `C++` file by using ODBC driver `api` provided by Oracle.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed so, but it's nice to get some sort of confirmation on this.